# How to prevent "Address already in use" error (errno 48) for Python Django Project

Tags: python, django, shell, server

I want to know how to *prevent* this error from always happening to me, *not* how to kill it when it does happen.

When I do "python manage.py runserver_plus", I usually get the error "Address already in use" when I run this command again after using the shell_plus.  I am often switching back and forth from "python manage.py shell_plus" and "runserver_plus". Am I quitting my server correctly? I quit the server via "ctrl + C" and I quit the shell using quit().

Thank you very much!

Comment: `runserver` is only used in development, so it's always safe to kill or `ctrl + c`. It's nothing of a big deal and you shouldn't do it often, I wonder why do you bother by that. Technically you don't need to quit your server, because when your python code is updated, the server will reload.

Comment: Hmm, then how do I ensure the "previous Django processes" you mention are finished before I "ctrl + c"? It's more of an annoyance to me. Glad I'm not doing anything to bad though. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing to ensure, as I mentioned before, you shouldn't exit/restart your server very often, because the server will reload itself. I'm not sure what's your level of tolerance, but it might happen to me only once a week, because I almost never stop my server.

Comment: Or you are looking for solution of how to get rid of the error? Just `ps aux | grep runserver_plus` and kill the process that's still running.

Comment: Yeah I start/stop it a lot since I'm working on different projects. I guess I could keep it going. New to a lot of this. Thanks, Shang!

Comment: Run your projects on different ports then. They shouldn't step into each other: `python manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000`.